# Magento putting template name in URL

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, magento-1.4

This weekend my webserver wen't down.

Today I arrived at work and noticed my links ain't working. For instance: www.domain.com/shoes.html (shoes being the product category) redirects to a not found page.

I've noticed that www.domain.com/template_name/shoes.html works exactly as expected.

So what's up with that? How can I revert magento to not put the template name in the URL?

Answer (score 2):

did you check you url rewrites?  It is done by your sever, so the reset may have screwed it up

Comment: I did, they were on. Apparently it messed my "Add Store Code to Urls" option. It was set to "No" and somehow it changed to "Yes". It wasn't the template name after all, it was the store code.

Answer (score 0):

From your question:

> SOLVED: add store code to URL was enabled.